# Getting error while printing jasper report from java Caused by: java.awt.print.PrinterException: No print service found

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

> Caused by: java.awt.print.PrinterException: No print service found. at
>   sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1305) at
>   sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1277) at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPages(JRPrinterAWT.java:205)
>
> Error getting when trying to print *JasperReports* report from *Java*
>   code

Below is code I tried, it works in some OS but problem in window7

```
 try {
    String report = args[0];
    String printText = args[1];
    String expiryDate = args[2];
    String printerName = args[3];

    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    hm.put("printText", printText);
    hm.put("expiryDate", expiryDate);

    InputStream templateAsStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(report);

    System.out.println(" \n compile report");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(templateAsStream);

    // submit parameters 
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("param1", "jasper report ...");
    parameters.put("param2", "...rules");

    System.out.println("fill the compiled template");

    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hm, new JREmptyDataSource());

    System.out.println("\n Page Count" + jp.getPages().size());

    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();

    printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName(printerName, null));
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

    JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printServiceAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);

    System.out.println("export to printer");

    JasperPrintManager.printReport(jp, false);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    System.out.println("Died");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't find any printer so it cannot print.

Comment: Whats printerName and how is it defined?

Comment: Well, a little late but can help further people: (on windows) -> Run -> cmd -> net start spooler.